# Use Xtable to do plus minus

Tags: tables, r, xtable

I am using a similar dataset to the following:

```
a= c("Fruits", "Adam","errorA", "steve", "errorS",
     "apples", 17.1,2.22, 3.2,1.1,
     "oranges", 3.1,2.55, 18.1,3.2 )
a_table=data.matrix(t(matrix(a,nrow=5)))
```

I would like to plus minus every second column starting from errorA (using xtable/ hmisc)

example output (ignoring decimals):

```
 Fruits && Adam && Steve \\
 Apples && 17\pm 2 && 3 \pm 1 \\
 Oranges && 3\pm 2 && 18 \pm 3\
```

Additionally is there any way I can have just to 2 d.p.?

Comment: I don't think that the export-to-Latex features of the R Project's `hmisc` package quite run to that. You might need to do some editing by hand or use a small Python/Perl/Awk/etc script to make your tables.